# Pass backend generated data as a webpack module

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm building SPA website using ExpressJS as a backend server and webpack with grunt.

But I want to pass some of express session's data as a module which could be loaded in my **app.js**

**app.js** (clinet)

```
var userData = require("userData");
```

**server.js** (server)

```
app.get("/test", function(req, res, next){
    res.render('view', {});
});
```

**view.pug**

```
html
    head
        script(src="app.js")
        script.
            // I want to pass this
            var sessionData = {name: "name", id: 123};
            // how to use webpackJsonp to define sessionData as userData module?
```

I don't want to make extra HTTP request from **app.js** to fetch user data.

I know that separated chunks is using **webpackJsonp** to define modules, but  how to define this "**dynamic generated module**" ?